# Cognos Promptmany function

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

I'm trying to use promptmany function to make the prompt optional to the user incase didn't select be default value as arrival announced the thing here when i use the function :

[STAGES] in (#promptmany ('STAGES','string','Arrival announced')#)

I get following error

XQE-V5-0011

```
    V5 syntax error found in expression "[STAGES] in (Arrival announced)", invalid token "Arrival" found after "[STAGES] in (".
```

Details
RSV-SRV-0042 Trace back:RSReportService.cpp(747): XQEException: CCL_CAUGHT: RSReportService::processImpl()RSReportServiceMethod.cpp(258): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: RSReportServiceMethod::process(): promptPagingForward_RequestRSASyncExecutionThread.cpp(848): XQEException: RSASyncExecutionThread::checkExceptionRSASyncExecutionThread.cpp(305): XQEException: CCL_CAUGHT: RSASyncExecutionThread::runImpl(): promptPagingForward_RequestRSASyncExecutionThread.cpp(904): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: RSASyncExecutionThread::processCommand(): promptPagingForward_RequestExecution/RSRenderExecution.cpp(587): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: RSRenderExecution::executeAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(323): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyAssembly/RSLayoutAssembly.cpp(79): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: RSLayoutAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(417): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchChildrenAssemblyForwardAssembly/RSReportPagesAssembly.cpp(178): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: RSReportPagesAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(367): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyAssembly/RSPageAssembly.cpp(314): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: RSPageAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(367): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyAssembly/RSTableRowAssembly.cpp(177): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: RSTableRowAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(367): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyAssembly/RSTableCellAssembly.cpp(151): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: RSTableCellAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(417): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchChildrenAssemblyForwardAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(367): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyAssembly/RSAssembly.cpp(677): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: RSAssembly::createListIteratorAssembly/RSAssembly.cpp(732): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: RSAssembly::createListIteratorRSQueryMgr.cpp(519): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: RSQueryMgr::getListIteratorRSQueryMgr.cpp(586): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: RSQueryMgr::getResultSetIteratorRSQueryMgr.cpp(678): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: RSQueryMgr::createIteratorRSQueryMgrBasic.cpp(279): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: RSQueryMgrBasic::executeRsapiCommandRSQueryMgrExecutionHandlerImpl.cpp(170): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: RSQueryMgrExecutionHandlerImpl::execute()QFSSession.cpp(1153): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: QFSSession::ProcessDoRequest()QFSSession.cpp(1151): XQEException: CCL_CAUGHT: QFSSession::ProcessDoRequest()QFSSession.cpp(1108): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: QFSSession::ProcessDoRequest()QFSConnection.cpp(788): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: QFSConnection::ExecuteQFSQuery.cpp(213): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: QFSQuery::Execute v2XQEConnector.cpp(289): XQEException: CCL_THROW: XQEConnector::send

Can't put my hand on the problem

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Add more single quotes to default value.

```
[STAGES] in (#promptmany ('STAGES','string','''Arrival announced''')#)
```

or

```
[STAGES] in (#promptmany ('STAGES','string',sq('Arrival announced'))#)
```

Comment: What would the syntax be if we wanted multiple default answers?
i.e. IN('Arrived', 'Arrival announced')